# VBA excel Assigning resources to a task in MS Project

Tags: excel, ms-project, vba

I am trying to build a simple schedule from an excel 'database' with MS Project.

I am running into multiple runtime errors, but I dont care so much about that, I just would like to understand how to assign a resource that I have pulled into a variable to a task. I can add the resource to the project, but I dont know how to assign it to a given task. Here's what I have:

```
Sub ExcelToProjectProto()
Dim oPrjApp, oPrj As Object
Set oPrjApp = MSProject.Application
Dim strJobName, strForeman, strCrane, strLocation, strPieces As String
Dim dStart, dEnd As Date
Dim lRow, lCol, lRevenue As Long
Dim rsCrane, rsForeman As Resource

oPrjApp.Visible = True
Set oPrj = oPrjApp.Projects.Add
oPrj.Title = "Test"

For lRow = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'pulling data from excel
    strJobName = Cells(lRow, 1).Value
    strCrane = Cells(lRow, 2).Value
    strForeman = Cells(lRow, 3).Value
    dStart = Cells(lRow, 4).Value
    dEnd = Cells(lRow, 6).Value
    lRevenue = Cells(lRow, 8).Value
    strPieces = Cells(lRow, 9).Value
    strLocation = Cells(lRow, 10).Value

    oPrj.Tasks.Add.Name = strJobName & "- " & strLocation & " (" & strPieces & " ea)"
    oPrj.Tasks(lRow - 1).Start = dStart
    oPrj.Tasks(lRow - 1).Finish = dEnd
    If Not ExistsInCollection(oPrj.Resources, strCrane) Then oPrj.Resources.Add.Name = strCrane
    If Not ExistsInCollection(oPrj.Resources, strForeman) Then oPrj.Resources.Add.Name = strForeman
    'Set rsCrane = oPrj.Resources(strCrane)     ''trying to setup the resources, I get an error here
    'Set rsForeman = oPrj.Resources(strForeman)   '' same thing as above line.

'trying to assign a resource

    'oPrj.Tasks(lRow - 1).Assignments.ResourceName.Add strCrane
    'oPrj.Tasks(lRow - 1).Assignments.ResourceName.Add strForeman

Next

Set oPrjApp = Nothing
Set oPrj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a way how.

This definitely isnt the best way, but after I added the resources in these lines:

```
If Not ExistsInCollection(oPrj.Resources, strCrane) Then oPrj.Resources.Add.Name = strCrane
If Not ExistsInCollection(oPrj.Resources, strForeman) Then oPrj.Resources.Add.Name = strForeman
```

I then have to loop through the all the resources I have added and match up the current ones and set them to rsCrane and rsForeman properties respectively:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    If oPrj.Resources(i).Name = strCrane Then
        Set rsCrane = oPrj.Resources(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
For i = 1 To 100
    If oPrj.Resources(i).Name = strForeman Then
        Set rsForeman = oPrj.Resources(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Then I use the following command to assign :

```
rsCrane.Assignments.Add TaskID:=(lRow - 1)
rsForeman.Assignments.Add TaskID:=(lRow - 1)
```